# How to have two different intent filters for same activity?

Tags: android, intentfilter

Hi I'm integrating two different apps into my app.One is fitbit and other is pinterest.My problem is when ever they are redirected from browser after authentication, I cannot handle intent filters. Here is my code.

```
<activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard" />
        <activity
            android:name=".IntegrateActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_link_apps"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="Link" />
                <data android:host="redirect.html" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="pdkMYID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Only first filter is working. Does anybody know how to handle this,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want isn't actually multiple filters but multiple schemas, which is supported.

```
<activity
    android:name=".IntegrateActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_link_apps"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="Link" />
        <data android:scheme="pdkMYID" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

That way matching any of those schemas will redirect to your Activity.

Comment: okay thank you,but if i remove launchmode means it is not working any idea about this?

Comment: Launchmode is still there.

Comment: yes it is working,but without launch mode = single task it recreates same activity that launches browser.So if i use this means it is not working.So only I'm asking.Do you any idea about this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking here.

Comment: you cannot have uppercase letters in a schema